# deletion in AVL tree is not working properly in C

Tags: c

if i input 15,7,22,3 into this AVL tree, and then i delete 22, the tree then displays only 15. what happened to 7 and 3?? also when i enter the data in this particular order -> 15,7,3,22 and then i delete 22, the program then seems to work fine, i get 15,7 and 3 as my output which is fully balanced. this is very strange. please help me out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int height;
};
struct node *tree=NULL;

int height(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree==NULL)
        return -1;
    else{
        int lh=height(tree->left);
        int rh=height(tree->right);

        if(lh>rh)
            return 1+lh;
        else
            return 1+rh;
    }
}

int max(int a,int b)
{
    return ((a < b)?b:a);
}

int getbalance(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree==NULL)
        return 0;
    return (height(tree->left)-height(tree->right));
}

struct node *rr(struct node *y)
{
   struct node *x,*t2;
   x=y->left;
   t2=x->right;

   x->right=y;
   y->left=t2;

   return x;
};

struct node *ll(struct node *x)
{
    struct node *y,*t2;
    y=x->right;
    t2=x->left;

    y->left=x;
    x->right=t2;

    return y;
};

struct node *newNode(int val)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->data=val;
    ptr->left=ptr->right=NULL;
    ptr->height=1;
    return ptr;
};

struct node *create(struct node *tree,int val)
{
    if(tree==NULL)
        return newNode(val);
    else if(val < tree->data)
        tree->left=create(tree->left,val);
    else if(val > tree->data)
        tree->right=create(tree->right,val);
    else
    {
        printf("\n duplicate value ignored");
        return tree;
    }
    tree->height=1+max(height(tree->left),height(tree->right));
    int balance=getbalance(tree);

    if(balance>1 && val<tree->left->data)
        return rr(tree);
    else if(balance<-1 && val>tree->right->data)
        return ll(tree);
    else if(balance>1 && val>tree->left->data)
    {
        tree->left=ll(tree->left);
        return rr(tree);
    }
    else if(balance<-1 && val<tree->right->data)
    {
        tree->right=rr(tree->right);
        return ll(tree);
    }
    return tree;
};

struct node *inordersuccesor(struct node *tree)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=tree;
    while(ptr->left!=NULL)
    {
        ptr=ptr->left;
    }
    return ptr;
}

struct node *delnode(struct node *tree,int val)
{
    if(tree==NULL)
        return 0;
    else if(val<tree->data)
        tree->left=delnode(tree->left,val);
    else if(val>tree->data)
        tree->right=delnode(tree->right,val);
    else
    {
        struct node *temp;
        if(tree->left==NULL)
        {
            temp=tree->right;
            free(tree);
            return temp;
        }
        else if(tree->right==NULL)
        {
            temp=tree->left;
            free(tree);
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp=inordersuccesor(tree->right);
            tree->data=temp->data;
            tree->right=delnode(tree->right,temp->data);
        }
    }

    int balance=getbalance(tree);

if(balance==2 && getbalance(tree->left)>=0)
    return rr(tree);
else if(balance==2 && getbalance(tree->left)==-1)
{
    tree->left=ll(tree->left);
    return rr(tree);
}
else if(balance==-2 && getbalance(tree->right)<=-0)
    return ll(tree);
else if(balance==-2 && getbalance(tree->right)==1)
{
    tree->right=rr(tree->right);
    return ll(tree);
}
    
    return tree;
};

void display(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree!=NULL)
    {
        display(tree->left);
        printf("\t%d",tree->data);
        display(tree->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int val,option;
    do{
        printf("\n 1. create");
        printf("\n 2. display");
        printf("\n 3. find height");
        printf("\n 4. balance factor");
        printf("\n 5. delete node");
        printf("\n 6. exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: printf("\n enter val: ");
                scanf("%d",&val);
                tree=create(tree,val);
                break;
            case 2: display(tree);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\n height [%d]\n",height(tree));
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("\n balance factor = [%d]",getbalance(tree));
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("\n delete node: ");
                scanf("%d",&val);
                delnode(tree,val);
                break;
        }
    }while(option!=6);
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the value returned by `delnode`.

Comment: When the input is 15,7,22,3 the tree is always balanced when it's being built. The 15 is the initial root and remains the root. But when you delete the 22 the tree becomes unbalanced, and needs to be rotated. When the input is 15,7,3,22 the tree is unbalanced after the 3, and the rotation moves the 7 to the root, with the 15 as the right child. Adding and then deleting the 22 doesn't require any rotations.

Comment: in main, `delnode(tree,val);` ==> `tree = delnode(tree,val);` would be a good place to start.

Comment: thanks for the replies, i understand how this works now <3

Comment: running the posted code through the C compiler results in several instances of the warning: `untitled.c:62:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]`  due to a `;` after the end of a function